# Android webview content size too small after Lollipop 5.0

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium

After android 5.0 responsive page not shown correctly. 
On android 4.2 "m.facebook.com" is like this
[android 4.2 webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz69D.png)

On android 6.0 m.facebook.com is like this
[android 6.0 webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Mvo.png)

Android 6.0 webview content is too small. Correct display must be like 4.2 webview display. Webview settings like this.

```
s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

thank for your help

Comment: I resolved problem. When setLayoutParams() method page showed correctly. Before i used only layout(left, top, right, bottom) method. Because my webview in viewgroup. Now i am using both of .layout(l,t,r,b) and setLayoutParams() methods.